# SharePoint Server Daily Check Automation Script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, developer

To monitor SharePoint Server 2013 Daily checkup, I have used the script from the below link and its working as expected except with related to search.

http://abhayajoshi.blogspot.com/2016/05/sharepoint-server-daily-check.html

I’m getting below errors related to search when executing the script. Can someone please assist on this?
[image]

Also as part of script I could see that there is CrawlTopology ID as shown below. Could you please help me on how to get the CrawlTopology ID in my server?

```
$SPCrawlComponent = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlComponent -SearchApplication "Enterprise Search Service" -CrawlTopology "a03a58cf-3f1d-4dcd-9cd2-f8267bc6fd07"|
```

Answer (score 0):

Only for the error, it seems that you did not replace the "Enterprise Search Service" with the name of search service application in your farm.

Besides, it seems you are using a very old script. The cmdlet `"Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlComponent"` is no longer used in SharePoint 2013.

I will suggest you to find another script for this farm.